# Counting Number of Object from each Type - Instanceof or getClassName

Tags: java, instanceof

I have three classes - `One`, `Two extends One`, `Three extends Two`

I have to write a method to count how many instances of each class exists in an `ArrayList<One>`.

```
ArrayList<One> v = new ArrayList<>(3);
    v.add(new One();
    v.add(new Two();
    v.add(new Three();
```

**The working code:**

```
public static void test2(ArrayList<One> v){
    String className = "";
    int countOne = 0, countTwo = 0, countThree = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <v.size() ; i++) {
        className = v.get(i).getClass().getSimpleName();
        if (className.equals("One")){
            countOne++;
        }
        else if (className.equals("Two")){
            countTwo++;
        }
        else{
            countThree++;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("One = "+countOne + "Two = " + countTwo + "Three = " +countThree);

}
```

**The not working code - with Instanceof**

```
public static void test2(ArrayList<One> v){
    String className = "";
    int countOne = 0, countTwo = 0, countThree = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <v.size() ; i++) {
        if (v.get(i) instanceof One){
            countOne++;
        }
        else if (v.get(i) instanceof Two){
            countTwo++;
        }
        else{
            countThree++;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("One = "+countOne + "Two = " + countTwo + "Three = " +countThree);

}
```

Why doesn't my code works with `instanceof`? Isn't it supposed to fetch the "right" type of the object?

Thanks.

Comment: Because anything that's a `Two` is also a `One`.

Comment: From [Oracle's tutorial on Equality, Relational, and Conditional Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html): "*The `instanceof` operator compares an object to a specified type. You can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular interface.*" If you want to count a `Two` as a `One` and a `Two`, remove the `else`'s, so you have a sequence of `if`'s.

Comment: @AndyTurner I see, but in my printing the instances of "One" is 3 (all of the array) and "Two" = 0. Is it because 'instanceof' selects only one class?

Comment: @Alan It's because the `else if` is not entered after determining that the class is an instance of `One`.

Comment: Pedantically, `v` can also contain null, which is not an instance of anything, even though it can be assigned to references of any type. If you count something in the `else` case, you would count nulls too. It depends on what you are trying to do, but you might want to explicitly check an instanceof in this case too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because anything that's a `Two` or a `Three` is also a `One`, so everything matches the first condition.

Put the check for `Three` first; then the check for `Two`; then `One` last.

Comment: Thank you! Got it.